# Does prestiging the shield in Trimps revert it to health?

Tags: trimps

There is an upgrade (found from the rare map The Block, level 10; I found it while farming gems on another map) which causes the shield to grant block value instead of health. It's still possible to find shield prestige upgrades, and they make no mention of block value (only health). Will purchasing one of these upgrades (in this case, Supershield 2) cause my shield (currently a Shield III) to revert to health values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It will not**

The item description states that this is a permanent upgrade.

[image]

Comment: Just tested this and you are correct. +1. The next tier of Shield (Shield IV) is offering me 330 block. Note that since doing this removes all of your current shield bonuses, I recommend you wait to do this until you can buy a few tiers. The starting price was 3 million wood.